# Linux equivalent of Windows Wireless Hosted Network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Is there in Linux any equivalent of Windows's [Wireless Hosted Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

I want to use my laptop as wifi repeater, connecting a phone to the laptop's own wireless network which gets routed to the wireless network the computer is connected to.

Please don't try to find me workarounds like "just connect your phone to the wireless network" and stay in topic, or I'd have to make a longer explanation. I'm doing Android development, I just have to create a wifi on computer, connect phone to it and trick with broadcast receivers

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have two physical wireless interfaces on your computer, or just one?  The HostAP suggestion below is a good one, but I don't think you'll be able to connect to your main wireless network AND host your own network with just one interface.

Comment: Only one wireless card. In Windows, this works thanks to a virtual wireless adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this feature depends on wireless card driver but there is such functionality in linux as well:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw/vif

Answer (score 0):

HostAP is "a user space daemon for access points, and is probably what you are looking for. (you can also look at the madwifi project).   Not all network cards are supported, but a reasonable range are.